# Add title to UIActivityViewController (iOS)

Tags: ios, title, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to add a title to UIActivityViewController? just a plain title bar, no animation needed.

here i found an [example](https://github.com/an0/WLActivityViewController), but it's for iOS 8+, my device is running iOS7 (crash on my device, even after i removed many crash lines).

one more thing, if adding a title bar (or title view) is possible, i think may be we can add another colorful icon view to cover a custom Action button (apple requires action button to be in gray), so we will have colored action button without using the private api : _activityImage. maybe this will still be rejected by Apple because its being colorful.

thank you.